# Android MulticastSocket.joinGroup doesn't trigger sending IGMP message

Tags: android

Code:

```
MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket();
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("230.230.230.1");
s.joinGroup(addr);
//...
```

On Ubuntu 14.04, when I run it, I can see IGMPv2 "Membership Report group 230.230.230.1" message out. But on Android, no such packet is seen.

Such packet is a must to notify router about IGMP membership when user calls joinGroup (or setsockopt in C), right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that many devices are shipped without support for multicast built into the kernel.  Open an adb shell and do

```
cat /proc/net/igmp
```

If it's not there, the kernel has been built without CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST.  You're basically SOL without rooting your device and/or flashing custom firmware.

This is a sad state of affairs.

Comment: @pengguang001 Does NetworkInterface.supportsMulticast() show this incompatibility? Does it return false?

Comment: Yes, /proc/net/igmp is absent, and CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST not defined. Kernel still support multicast, without membership reporting.