# How to figure out if the router supports multicast?

Tags: android, router, multicast

I want to check in the app whether wifi router supports mulitcast. My app receives multicast to find device, but some routers don't support mulicast or configure to disable mulicast in their router setting, so we cannot find device in this router at all.

If the app finds that the current router doesn't support multicast, I can show user this information. But I don't find related API. Is that possible? My code:

```
mMultiCastSocket = new MulticastSocket(LSSDP_PORT);
mMultiCastSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
mMultiCastSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(32 * 1024);
mMultiCastSocket.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress(LSSDP_MULTICAST_ADDRESS, LSSDP_PORT), NetworkInterface.getByName(name));
```

Comment: Not only routers but also some phones are compiled without multicast support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293456/why-does-multicast-reception-not-work-on-some-android-devices

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it more understandable? Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)